# what to use custom URL structure in magento extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We are using magento team extension and URL for all team member list is www.sitename.com/meet-the-team/ and by default the team member detail page url is www.sitename.com/meet-the-team/index/index/id/18/

We want url of to SEO friendly like www.sitename.com/meet-the-team/membername for e.g. www.sitename.com/meet-the-team/sahilmonpara

Answer (score 0):

Just make URL rewrite for each developer in Magento Admin. Such rewrite rule will look similar to product rules